# fabric8 Kubernetes Client Config keeps referencing kubeconfig

Tags: kubernetes, fabric8, kubeconfig, fabric8-kubernetes-client

I am trying to set up a custom Kubernetes Client using the following

```
Config config = new ConfigBuilder()
        .withMasterUrl(eksEndpoint)
        .withOauthTokenProvider(authTokenProvider)
        .withTrustCerts()
        .build();
return new KubernetesClientBuilder().withConfig(config).build();
```

This works fine when I do not hacve a kube cionfig file configured. But when I do it tries to reference it and causes this failure.

```
mapping values are not allowed here
in reader, line 3, column 11:
    "kind": "ExecCredential",
```

I have gone through as much documentation as I can find but can't see as to why fabric8 keeps referencing my kube config.
Removing the kube config is not an option.
I have tried adding `withAutoConfigure(false)` but this has made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to not automatically pick up `.kube/config` `Config.empty()` should be provided into the builder constructor:

```java
Config config = new ConfigBuilder(Config.empty())
        .withMasterUrl(eksEndpoint)
        .withOauthTokenProvider(authTokenProvider)
        .withTrustCerts()
        .build();
```

Comment: Thanks very much that worked! Accepted and +1.
Any chance you have a source for the solution? Tried looking for ages.

Comment: @DarraghMacKenna : A user had reported same issue on GitHub 3 years ago https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/issues/2319